# Is $G$ a lie group if left multiplication is smooth and multiplication is smooth near $e$?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, lie-groups, topological-groups

Suppose $G$ is a smooth manifold and also a *topological* group. Also suppose that left multiplication $L_g : G \rightarrow G$ is smooth for any $g \in G$. Finally suppose that the multiplication map is smooth in a neighborhood of the identity $e$.  By this i mean there exists open $U$ containing $e$ such that $\mu : U \times U \rightarrow M$ is smooth.

**Can we conclude that $\mu$ makes G into a Lie group (with the given smooth structure)?**

I know there are some strong theorems we could use here. Like the answer to one of hilbert's problems. I was hoping there was an elementary way to see it. I've tried writing the multiplication map near two different points as a composition of these maps, but I cant get things to work out.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Do you make any assumptions about the smoothness of the inversion operation? Or is part of the question whether we can infer from the properties of $\mu$ that $(g,h) \mapsto g^{-1}h$ is also smooth?

Comment: @Tom , Yes i didnt want to assume that inversion is smooth. Maybe that is a necessary hypothesis?  In that case it follows pretty immediately because you can translate $U$ containing $g$ and $V$ containing $h$ to the origin, invert one of the factors, multiply, and then left multiply by $gh$, right?

Comment: @Tom , i guess maybe it does sound kind of implausible that my hypotheses could say something about the smoothness of inversion since they only say things about G as a "smooth monoid"

Comment: Although I'm not sure about this (I can't think of a counter example), I do think that *if* it was straight forward to show that local smoothness of multiplication implies smoothness of inversion, then the material would often be introduced through smoothness of multiplication and from there smoothness of inversion would be deduced.

Comment: @Tom Thats a very good point. If this were true, there would be no need to put "inverse is smooth" as a Lie group axiom! Oh, except that ive assumed inversion is *continuous*...

Comment: Actually, the axiom that "the inverse map is smooth" *is* redundant.  In fact, the fact that $\mu$ is smooth on $U$ is enough to conclude the inverse is smooth on a (possibly smaller) neighborhood of $e$.  This is a good excercise using the implicit function theorem ;-)

Comment: To clarify:  I don't know if one can prove that inversion is smooth on all of $G$ based on the fact that $\mu$ is smooth only on a small neighborhood, but one can at least prove that inversion is smooth near $e$.

Comment: @JasonDeVito "I don't know if one can prove that inversion is smooth on all of G based on the fact that μ is smooth only on a small neighborhood" Well, if we assume multiplication and inversion are continuous then we can deduce they are both globally smooth (and analytic). Although I am not sure what happens if we drop that assumption... Probably you can deduce it anyway...